# Sass Mixin multiple properties in a loop

Tags: sass

I'm lost and not sure why this compiles but doesn't output anything. Also not even sure if I'm approaching this correctly. I started using a mixin within a loop to define a bunch of colors. This works great, except that depending on the place I may need to pass the colors to the color, border-color, or background-color properties. Also, I may need to pass the same color to one of those properties in a :hover state. This compiles, yet doesn't actually output anything if called.

```css
// Category Colors
$category-1: #29b473 !default;
$category-2: #60e2c9 !default;
$category-3: #25a9e0 !default;
$category-4: #2b52ff !default;
$category-5: #c5a0ff !default;
$category-6: #ea2f69 !default;
$category-7: #ec1c24 !default;
$category-8: #f6921e !default;
$category-9: #cccc00 !default;

$categories: () !default;
$categories: map-merge((
 "red": $category-1,
 "blue": $category-2,
 "black": $category-3,
 "green": $category-4,
 "yellow": $category-5,
 "pink": $category-6,
 "gray": $category-7,
 "orange": $category-8,
 "brown": $category-9,
), $categories);

// Mixins
@mixin category($parent, $color, $props, $hovers:null) {
 #{$parent} {
  @each $prop in $props {
   $prop:$color;
  }
  @if ($hovers) {
   &:hover {
    @each $hover in $hovers {
     $hover:$color;
    }
   }
  } @else {}
 }
}

// Testing
@each $color, $value in $categories {
 @include category('.xyz-#{$color}', $value, (color, border-color), background-color);
}
```

Ignore the oddities with the colors please and that they aren't actually the colors that they are labeled.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, needed to change my statements being used for property names to this format:

## {$prop}, and #{$hover}.